# how to transfer apex class sandbox to production

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I created some class and trigger in sandbox. Class is type of Date Helper and I used in my trigger. I tried to transfer my production from sandbox. I fail. I downloaded Force IDE, and copied my code here. So, My trigger is gone but my apex class is not created on production.

How could I createa apex class to production.

Our salesorce is enterprice Edition.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is from eclipse IDE you have to create a project to your sandbox, select the items that you want to sincronice and get those, then you have to do a right click deploy to salesforce...and select you prod environment.

If this doesn't solve your problem give us more info about:
Wich error you got?
How many code coverage do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Again I am Kerem Bekman on diffrent Account,

This is my class,

```
public class DateProcess
{
public DateProcess()
{
}
public Boolean isDaysOff(Datetime dt)
{
    if(dt.format('E') == 'Sat' || dt.format('E') == 'Sun')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public Datetime getLastBussinessDateOfMonth(Datetime dt)
{
    //Datetime temp = new DateTime();
    while(this.isDaysOff(dt))
    {
        dt = dt.addDays(-1);
    }
    return dt;
}
}
```

I created this class in Force IDE on sandbox project. So I clicked 'Deploy to Server'. My class is gone to production but

Only

```
public class DateProcess() {}
```

I looked Apex Test Runner on IDE

DateProcess (ApexClass) -- 9 line is not tested. %0 covered.

How could i test my class. I dont know.

Comment: Rather than posting additional questions as answers, you may want to try editing the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I did.

This is testing method.

You have to test your code in your class or another class like this.

```
public class DateHelper
{
    public DateHelper()
    {
    }

    public Boolean isDaysOff(Datetime dt)
    {
        if(dt.format('E') == 'Sat' || dt.format('E') == 'Sun')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    static testMethod void testisDaysOff(){     
        DateHelper dh = new DateHelper();
        Datetime dt = Datetime.now();
        Test.startTest();

        Boolean ido1 = dh.isDaysOff(dt);
        dt = dt.addDays(-2);
        Boolean ido2 = dh.isDaysOff(dt);

        Datetime last = dh.getLastBussinessDateOfMonth(dt);

        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(false, ido1);
        System.assertEquals(true, ido2);
    }

    public Datetime getLastBussinessDateOfMonth(Datetime dt)
    {
        //Datetime temp = new DateTime();
        while(this.isDaysOff(dt))
        {
            dt = dt.addDays(-1);
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Deploy your code to production with your force ide. So Click run test on salesforce.

That's all..